# CRM Ribbon Workbench - Hide + Button on Sub-Grid

Tags: button, dynamics-crm, ribbon, dynamics-crm-2013, crm-ribbon-workbench

I have a sub grid on a new entity called Issues, the sub grid is for another new entity called Cost Detail.
I have them both loaded into my solution called Issue, and have opened issue in the ribbon workbench.

What I want to do is when you are on the Issue form and can see the sub-grid I want to be able to hide the + button which is displayed. However when I have hidden this button in the ribbon workbench it also hides the add new button in the 'Associated View' therefore no records can be added.

How do I do it so that only the + button on the sub grid is hidden and not the other view?

Comment: Out of curiosity what is the use case?  The subgrid and associated view are (mostly) functionally equivalent which is why the same rule controls the behavior on both.

Comment: I've noticed that when on the subgrid when + is clicked it will allow the user to select previous records from cost detail, which I do not want, I have created cost detail to be similar to quote detail where a new record is required as it will then associate the cost detail to the issue record.

Comment: So removing the ability to add existing records on the subgrid would be as good (or better) of a fix?

Comment: If removing the + button completely is not an option then yes removing the ability to add existing would be the next option, as data is coming from a third entity when on the entity cost detail I would prefer users to have to open cost detail form rather than adding from a sub grid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT**:
In order to hide the add button, you either need to take away create privileges to the role that the user is in or you could do a hack(unsupported) like this:

```
function hideAddButton(){
    var addButton = $('#NameOfGrid_addImageButton');
    if(addButton.size())
        addButton.hide();
    else
        setTimeout(hideAddButton, 1000);//checks every second to see if the button exists yet
}
```

and call the *hideAddButton* function on form load

Comment: Hi, if you see the above comments I don't really want people to add new records from the sub grid, with regards to quick create form would the javascript associated with the full form work on a quick create form?

Comment: The quick form is a normal form so the logic will work as soon as you will add to the quick creation form.

Comment: @BlueSam :) I put down a comment in regards to the quick create form. Is possible that i missed something.

Comment: @Draiden, the quick create form is a separate form, so no, the script from the full form wouldn't take effect.

Comment: @BlueSam Correct, in my post i wrote that it will work correctly as soon as you add the js to the quick create form. Maybe was unclear sorry about that.

Comment: @BlueSam Sorry for this small question, but how can I get that image schema name used on a Sub Grid (System Sub Grid)?

Answer (score 2):

There is one answer that I found. If you have a field that unique for that entity, then you can do it with a simple javascript code. 
Here is steps that you must follow in ribbon workbench:

1. Right click the button and customise button.
2. Add an enable rule, in Steps section add an Custom Javascript Rule, that contains your library and function name, please make sure that default is true.
   This must be in your javascirpt library :

```js
function hideAddNew(){
 if(Xrm.Page.getAttribute("yourField")){
  return false;
 }
 else {
  return true;
 }
}
```

3. Add a command that contains the enable rule we created.
4. Add the command to button.

That's it. I test it, it is working.